# is there an exception handling available for element() function when index>list of values?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

```
data"aws_network_interface""node1"{
  id="eni-0dfe5asdf7ajk5"
}
```

the output of above data source is a list of Private_ips  with the length of 4
as

> [10.198.10.1,10.198.10.2,10.198.10.3,10.198.10.4]

Here I am trying to create NLB with the target by IP.

I am also confused on how the index works in `element()` function -my requirement is to pick the 3rd element as [10.198.0.3] from the above list if my `var.lbcount=1` and when my `var.lbcount=2` I need to pick the 4th element from the above list as 10.198.10.4.

```
resource"aws_lb_target_group_attachment""tga"
     {
  target_group_arn="${aws_lb_target_group.tg.arn}"
  target_id="${element(data.aws_network_interface.node1.private_ips,4}"
       }
```

As I stated

```
index=4
```

I am getting **target_id as a 1st element in the list as [10.198.10.1] which is wrong,** how to throw an error or exception if the index is out of range of length of the list.

How can **I make sure we should only allow 1,2,3 as the index in element() function and if we pass 4,** which is more than the list of values the terraform to throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

In general, Terraform would use `list[0]` again if `length(LIST) = 3` and the current `count.index = 4`.

You can, however, use a simple conditional for your use-case (pseudocode):

```
count = "${var.MAX_INDEX > length(LIST) ? length(LIST) : var.MAX_INDEX"
```

This would set `count` to the *length of the list* if your `MAX_INDEX` is larger than the length of your list. Otherwise it would set count to your `MAX_INDEX`.

Comment: Thank you, in my requirement i do not want to loop through, i want to just pick the desired index. Can i  use something else than count to get the required index??

Comment: If the length of you list I'd recomment using the condition I mentioned above. Otherwise, if the index is fix, why not just use fixed indices and define the desired amount of resources fix?